# Error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" while looping

Tags: python, csv, email

I'm trying to parse only the replies to my emails, which are stored in a CSV file. I am making use of [this library](https://github.com/zapier/email-reply-parser) which seems to be geared at doing that. My CSV columns look like this:

```
Date    From Name   From Address   To   Subject    Message
```

What I want to do is read the `message` column, perform the cleaning function which is `EmailReplyParser.parse_reply(email_message)` and replace it with the cleaned emails.

This is what I have right now:

```
from email_reply_parser import EmailReplyParser
import csv

with open('D:/Harry_Potter.csv', encoding="utf8") as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf.readlines())

with open('D:/clean.csv', 'w') as outf:
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    for row in reader:
        EmailReplyParser.parse_reply(row['Message'])
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

This is the error I'm getting: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `row` is a list. You can only use integers as indices for lists, not strings (like `'Message'`).

Comment: Maybe you meant to use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead of  `csv.reader`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I can try replacing that, `DictReader` does look more appropriate. Is the other logic for replacing strings correct, though?

Comment: I guess not. You do not use the result of `EmailReplyParser.parse_reply` and `writer.writerows(reader)` does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: Also getting this error now: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` I guess its because the file is read and closed before it is parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop should be like this:

```
with open('D:/clean.csv', 'w') as outf:
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    # need to skip the title
    title = reader.__next__()
    for row in reader:
        EmailReplyParser.parse_reply(row[0].split()[-1])
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

Comment: Thank you! That solves the looping problem, although the emails are still not being cleaned by the function. [I've uploaded the file here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thedivtagguy/srishti23/main/hp.csv), would you be able to try it with the dataset?

Comment: What error do you get? I would advice asking a new question related to the parsing of emails with a reproducible example.

Comment: I'll do that right away. Also, the corrected loop that you've shared is supposed to go after I read in the file like this: `with open('D:/Harry_Potter.csv', encoding="utf8") as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf.readlines())`, correct?

Comment: I didn’t change anything in that part, so yeah.

Comment: I've asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65462597/error-parsing-emails-for-only-replies-with-python) with the dataset, if you'd like to take a look.