# Error parsing emails for only replies with Python

Tags: python, csv, email

I have this csv with a bunch of emails that I want to parse, [**uploaded here**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thedivtagguy/srishti23/main/hp.csv)

Using this [library](https://github.com/zapier/email-reply-parser) and thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65459236/14425671), we have this loop that would go over the CSV and apply the cleaning function `EmailReplyParser.parse_reply(email_message)` to each message:

```py
from email_reply_parser import EmailReplyParser
import csv
with open('D:/Harry_Potter.csv', encoding="utf8") as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf.readlines())
with open('D:/clean.csv', 'w') as outf:
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    # need to skip the title
    title = reader.__next__()
    for row in reader:
        EmailReplyParser.parse_reply(row[0].split()[-1])
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

However, this does not work.

It loops just fine, but emails are not cleaned. When I try it with a single message copy pasted from the CSV,

```
email = """I don't have an owl

On Saturday 18 June 2016, Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry <
no-reply@wufoo.com> wrote:

> HOGWARTS SCHOOL of WITCHCRAFT and WIZARDRY
>
> Headmaster: Albus Dumbledore
> (Order of Merlin, First Class, Grand Sorc., Chf. Warlock,
> Supreme Mugwump, International Confed. of Wizards)
>
> Dear Student,
>
> We are pleased to inform you that you have been accepted at Hogwarts
> School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. Please find enclosed a list of all
> necessary books and equipment.
>
> Term begins on 1 September. We await your owl by no later than 31 July.
>
>
> Yours sincerely,
>
> [image: image]
>
> Minerva McGonagall
>
> Deputy Headmistress
>
> Here is your ticket for the Hogwarts Express:
>
> [image: image]
>"""
```

It gives me the right result, like so:

```
EmailReplyParser.parse_reply(email)
Out[11]: "I don't have an owl"
```

Why is the CSV not being read correctly? (I've uploaded the CSV so that it can be tried without downloading).

Comment: Can you add the line from csv which actually generates the difference/issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I don't think its a particular line. However, I was wondering if this could be the issue. Does the file we've read in with the first `with` remain open long enough to be parsed by the second loop? What if its only the new, empty `clean.csv` which is trying to be parsed?

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the way to parse a csv row by reading your csv like this:

```
with open('D:/Harry_Potter.csv', encoding="utf8") as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
```

Then change your loop for writing to the csv. Code (change arguments for opening/closing the file):

```
from email_reply_parser import EmailReplyParser
import csv
with open('hp.csv', encoding="utf8") as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    with open('out.csv', 'w') as outf:
        # need to skip the title
        title = reader.__next__()
        for row in reader:
            # you need to store the return value from 'parse_reply'
            get_reply = EmailReplyParser.parse_reply(row[-1]) 
            # check what reply you get here
            print("Reply:", get_reply)
            outf.write(str(get_reply))
```

Comment: So I have this: https://pastebin.com/vCwibPqL but I'm getting a  `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` at `title = reader.__next__()`.

Comment: Do it within the `with` block where you open the csv file.

Comment: Sorry for the incessant questions, I'm fairly new to this. Is this what you mean? https://pastebin.com/rrNuqRhS I tried removing the `clean.csv` bit, to simply overwrite the existing file, but no look. Additionally, with the `print(get_reply)` I'm still able to see the quoted text in the output, so I don't think the string is parsed correctly anyway.

Comment: @Aman check the edit, I assume you just need to write one string (one row) to your output csv. Also, the input csv has some issue, so the loop will halt, you probably need to fix your csv.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back earlier, I was away from my laptop. It didn't work as expected and instead of single rows, I got text which was split into multiple columns ( see here https://i.imgur.com/CipZXCy.png). I ended up having to manually copy-paste 300 emails today morning. I think the issue is because the each entry in the `Message` column has multiple lines, maybe the csv module is not reading that in correctly?